Grease Pencil material preview slot shows the checkerboard background in Blender 4.1
This is a Grease Pencil material preview slot in Blender 4.1

This is a Grease Pencil material preview slot in Blender 4.0 and below

As you can see, there's the weird checkerboard background appears on the Grease Pencil in Blender 4.1.

This is expected behavior. AFAIK there is no way to change the material preview background.

But in Blender versions prior to 4.1, the material preview slot used to have a transparent background. @TheLabCat

@WW Maybe so, I don’t remember, but afaict this isn’t a problem. If you truly think it was a mistake, you can file a bug report. If you don’t believe it was a mistake but you’d like it changed back, you can make a suggestion on RightClickSelect.com
